# Why do we add i386 architecture to dpkg?

Tags: 64-bit, dpkg, 32-bit

Why do we add i386 architecture to dpkg, for installing on a 64 bit OS? Is it because this is a i386 binary?

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-skype-4-3-in-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the architecture to install the Skype package itself, but you do need it to install all the dependencies.

Also note that you don't need GDebi - the Software Centre is perfectly capable of handling deb files.